# Discord bot with python won't respond or register messages

Tags: python, discord, bots

My bot won't respond or reigster messages, why is this? In the logs is just prints out an empty message as if the user said nothing. "User said ' ' in (channel name)
Let me know if I should show more code please!

```
> @client.event 
> async def on_message(message):
> 
>     # preventing endless response loop
>     if message.author == client.user:
>         return
> 
>     #test function
>     if message.content == "hello":
>         print(message)
>         await message.channel.send("Hello there")
```

Comment: inside `if message.author == client.user` what if you [check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check) to see what the `author` and `user` are when it returns with nothing

Comment: You are following [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) right?

Comment: Yup I'm following https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html. Also I'm new to python, what do you mean exactly when you say check?

Comment: The bot seems to be working perfectly in private messages (dms) but not in public servers?

Comment: [message.author](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intent#discord.Message.author) returns differently when in public or private. Also I wonder if it has the right [intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intent#discord.on_message)

Comment: I think it does, I mean 
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

Comment: Does adding `Intents.messages` do anything?

Comment: client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.messages())

gives me a type error "alias_flag_value" object is not callable.

Comment: [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#a-primer-to-gateway-intents) doc page shows working with intents

Comment: I got it to work with intents.all()

I will handle it from here, thank you a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the intents correctly?

Your client needs to be initialised with the message contents intent:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Your application should also have the  have the message content intent on enabled in the developer portal as of August 1st 2022 (see https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ for more info)